# Running multiple amplitude estimations simulations

Tags: qiskit, optimization

I am working on a mini project investigating the scalability of quantum computing in the context of [option pricing](https://qiskit.org/ecosystem/finance/tutorials/03_european_call_option_pricing.html).

I have been following the above Finance API from Qiskit as an introduction, however, if I wanted to scale this for pricing multiple options simultaneously, I was wondering if there was a better method than the brute way of running them sequentially.

I have tried a few different methods - not sure if it's entirely correct or logical - such as executing the circuits but because the circuit is composed of P(X) and F gates, it will not work. I have also tried to do it using parallel computing via ThreadExecuter and DASK but the aforementioned issue occurred again. I have tried to use Python's multithreading library to run them parallel too but I feel that is a cop-out method and there should be something better for simultaneous amplitude estimations. My next idea is to (maybe) try using a Parameterized circuit.

How can I effectively run an amplitude estimation for multiple estimation problems simultaneously?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the stack exchange! In order to get a good answer, you will need to include more information on your problem. What are P(X) and F gates? What are the errors you are experiencing? Are you only interested in simulators, or do you want to use real quantum hardware too?

Comment: Hi Adrien, I updated the link to hopefully give more clarity on the general code solution. 
When I draw the circuit, the P(X) gate represents the lognormal probability distribution for the given mu and sigma, and the F gate represents the LinearAmplitude function. 

This is where I am stuck because I keep seeing code examples from Qiskit which Execute or use Sampler/Estimator primitives for a magnitude of different circuits, but is it not possible for Amplitude Estimation?

I would like to run multiple of them across real quantum hardware as part of my study.